# ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "content_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I'm currently building a rails 5 application in which a `shout` can be a `TextShout` or a `PhotoShout`. When creating a shout, `content_id` is not being pass in the params therefore raising a Not Null Value error. In the migration for the shout I can not find where the error is coming from. I have the following files.

show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @shout do |form| %>
<%= form.hidden_field :content_type, value: "TextShout" %>
  <%= form.fields_for :content do |content_form| %>
    <%= content_form.text_field :body, placeholder: "shout here!", required: true %>
    <%= content_form.submit "Shout!" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @shout do |form| %>
<%= form.hidden_field :content_type, value: "PhotoShout" %>
  <%= form.fields_for :content do |content_form| %>
    <%= content_form.file_field :image, required: true %>
    <%= content_form.submit "Shout!" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= render @shouts %>
```

migration/_make_shouts_polymorphic.rb

```
class MakeShoutsPolymorphic < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  class Shout < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true
  end
  class TextShout < ApplicationRecord; end
  def change
    change_table(:shouts) do |t|
      t.string :content_type
      t.integer :content_id
      t.index [:content_type, :content_id]
    end

    reversible do |dir|
      Shout.reset_column_information
      Shout.find_each do |shout|
        dir.up do
          text_shout = TextShout.create(body: shout.body)
          shout.update(content_id: text_shout.id, content_type: "TextShout")
        end
        dir.down do
          shout.update(body: shout.content.body)
          shout.content.destroy 
        end
      end
    end

    remove_column :shouts, :body, :string
  end
end
```

shouts_controller.rb

```
class ShoutsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @shout = Shout.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    shout = current_user.shouts.create(shout_params)
    redirect_to root_path, redirect_options_for(shout)
  end

  private

  def shout_params
    { content: content_from_params }
  end

  def content_from_params
    case params[:shout][:content_type]
    when "TextShout" then TextShout.new(text_shout_content_params)
    when "PhotoShout" then PhotoShout.new(photo_shout_content_params)
    end
  end

  def text_shout_content_params
    params.require(:shout).require(:content).permit(:body)
  end

  def photo_shout_content_params
    params.require(:shout).require(:content).permit(:image)
  end

  def redirect_options_for(shout)
    if shout.persisted?
      {notice: "Shouted Successfully"}
    else
      {alert: "Could not shout"}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

neither `text_shout_content_params` and `photo_shout_content_params` are permitting a `content_id`, but it looks like you're trying to (or at least you should be intending to) create one in your `content_from_params`

```
def content_from_params
  case params[:shout][:content_type]
    when "TextShout" 
      shout = TextShout.new(text_shout_content_params)
    when "PhotoShout"
      shout = PhotoShout.new(photo_shout_content_params)
  end
  shout.save!
  params[:shout][:content_id] = shout.id 
  params[:shout]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content to have an id you will have to create the shout using `create` instead of `new`. `create` will attempt to add a record to the database and will assign an id.

It may also be beneficial to use `create!` which will raise an error if the shout has invalid data and cannot be saved.

```
def content_from_params
  case params[:shout][:content_type]
  when "TextShout" then TextShout.create(text_shout_content_params)
  when "PhotoShout" then PhotoShout.create(photo_shout_content_params)
  end
end
```